# GeoExt Tree Panel Align Left

Tags: openlayers-3, extjs6, geoext3

I am new in ExtJS 6 and GeoExt3 but how do I align layers to my tree panel to the left of the panel. The layers are showing but on the right, I have tried align: 'left' on the panel and its not working, please help.

Comment: You should create a fiddle with your case, or at least provide some code,  because for now it's not clear what layout do you have. Is the tree panel a docked item of the panel, or are they both viewport items, or items inside a container with hbox layout?

Comment: 'region: 'east',
                    width: '30%',
                    items: [{
                        title: '<b>Data Menu</b>',
                        xtype: 'treepanel',
                        viewConfig: {
                            plugins: {ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'}
                        },
                        store: treeStore,
                        name: 'treelayers',
                        dataIndex: 'treelayers',
                        useArrows: true,
                        rootVisible: false '

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a [border](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.layout.container.Border.html) layout. Setting `region: "west"` for the `treepanel` wrapper container should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for response but can u explain more or show me an example

Comment: I mean that in the code you've provided in the comment, you should change the `region:"east"` to `region:"west"`, and it will align the treepanel to the left. Here is a fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/219k

Comment: Tried but still not working, I see the fiddle works fine but still not working for me

Comment: Tried but still not working, I see the fiddle works fine but still not working for me. I think the default is set to <i>align: 'right'</i> on my Ext, I have tried to re-create your fiddle but it still align to the right

Comment: It would be great if you could save your recreated fiddle and share it..